# Google Compute Engine Running a Nodejs App

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm unable to run a simple hello world application on a compute engine VM, which successfully runs locally and on Heroku:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port: ' + port);
});
```

Then looking at [Google's Node on GCP Demo](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/tutorials/bookshelf-on-compute-engine#creating_and_configuring_a_compute_engine_instance), I created a firewall rule to allow traffic to 8080 named "default-allow-http-8080" as linked [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wctlD.png)

The problem is when I visit http://[EXTERNAL_IP]:8080, it times out.  Is there something I'm missing?  I’m a beginner at Linux and new to networking, so any pointers are welcome!

Edit: After more googling, this was resolved by adding the extra argument to app.listen:

```
app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", callback);
```

Comment: where did you copy your app folder on the vm ? and how ? How many firewall rules did you create ?

Comment: I used SCP to copy the app to the home directory of the SSH user (adding my public key containing a username created a new user in the VM corresponding to that user).  I only created the 1 firewall rule that the demo link told me to do so--the rest were already there (and all rules are Allow, so shouldn't have any conflicts)

Comment: are you sure you executed the following : 

gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-http-8080 \
    --allow tcp:8080 \
    --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0 \
    --target-tags http-server \
    --description "Allow port 8080 access to http-server"

Comment: Yes, I edited the post with a link to the image of my firewall rules (2nd row).

Comment: Just edited the page again, found a solution from https://serverfault.com/questions/271824/node-js-is-not-accessible-from-external-ips-on-ubuntu!